# Questions vs. Commands

Tags: terminology, copywriting

Is there any consensus as to whether users respond better to prompts phrased in the form of a question or in the form of a command? For instance:

"Which application would you like to run?"

vs.

"Please choose an application"

Or is it inconsequential?

Answer (score 1):

While there isn't much research I could find upon this,

Asking a question doesn't necessary act as a prompt.

While I would definitely agree on using the question more if you were to speak with a Voice Assistant such as Google Now, SiRi or Cortana; in a Windows application with straightforward prompts such as **Click here to Start**, I think it's natural to go with the command.

It would be completely out of context to ask **Would you like to click here to Start?**

You are essentially encouraging the user to click on a particular application (assuming there isn't a default one or there couldn't be a compatible one that could be located), so using a command for a quick action by the user is appropriate. By using a question, you are basically having the user think about it for a couple of seconds longer before selecting.

As far as actions which have options one can select without the use of a Voice Assistant are concerned, I would definitely recommend to stick to the **Command** since it is straight forward, conveys what you need to do and does not have the user think a lot.